# imbalanced clustering by optimizing normalized cut

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I have been studying spectral graph partitioning and I found that this algorithm optimize normalized cut by taking equal size cluster, which might not be a real world scenario. Is there any algorithm that optimize normalized cut but not necessarily taking equal size cluster?

Comment: Aren't the size of the clusters usually related to the eigenvalues of the affinity matrix? Maybe you could estimate the biggest ones first as a help?

Comment: According to this site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation-based_object_categorization#Normalized_cuts you can use Lanczos algorithm, related to power iterations and Krylov subspace methods to drastically increase the efficiency of finding that eigenvalue & eigenvector you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to find an affinity matrix $\bf A$, for example:
   $${\bf A}_{ij} = \exp(-|{\bf D}_{ij}|)$$
where $\bf D$ is a distance matrix, for example:
   $${\bf D}_{ij} = |{\bf d}_i-{\bf d}_j|$$
Where $\bf d$ is your data vector ( assuming it 1 dimensional for simplicity ).

If you do this, then you can search for the second largest eigenvalue of your affinity matrix, and corresponding eigenvector, and your two directions for cut are positive real and negative real. So 0 as element in your eigenvector is the *cut decision boundary*. This will find cuts where the relation of the sizes of your clusters can be arbitrary.

To find one of the largest eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, popular methods include power iteration and Krylov subspace methods such as Lanczos iterations.

---

**EDIT** To solve the issue you face you may want to remove the *mean value* of your eigenvector. Otherwise 0 won't be the cut decision boundary as i claimed above.